# How to add css to option tag in select in VUE js

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I am trying to create a dropdown that looks like this. But Not able to add any CSS. Please let me know how to create customizable select dropdown in Vue ?

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Styling with Vue.js works just the same as without Vue.js. That said, are you using a standard HTML `<select>` element? Those are very limited in the way they can be styled, especially they can't be styles like you show in the image. You'll need to use a custom component (either Vue.js specific or not).

Answer (score 0):

just add a class to each option like this :
in your template :

```html
<select> 
<option class="custom_class_here"></option>
</select>
```

in your style:

```css
.custom_class_here{
customstyle: here
}
```

or

```css
select option{
stlye:here
}
```